# Solaris OS latest version for i386

Tags: solaris

I am running following solaris OS on I386 processors:

```
$ uname -a SunOS oobleck 5.10 Generic_127128-11 i86pc i386 i86pc $ CC -V CC: Sun C++ 5.8 Patch 121018-11 2007/05/02
```

I checked on Oracle's web page and it seems that there latest version is Solaris 10
sun-dot-om/software/solaris/releases.jsp

The instruction set is:

```
$ isainfo -kv
64-bit amd64 kernel modules
```

However when I look at the fixpacks available , for solaris 10 it says Solaris OS 5.10 http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/downloads/patches/ss12_patches.jsp

So I have 2 questions:

1. Does Solaris 10 mean 5.10?
2. What is the latest version of OS and fix pack I should upgrade the machine to ?

Answer (score 4):

Solaris 10 includes SunOS 5.10.   `uname -a` will show the SunOS version as you saw.   `cat /etc/release` will show the Solaris version.

Currently the latest version of Solaris 10 is Solaris 10 10/09.   Patches for it are available from http://support.oracle.com/ and require a support contract to download now.   (The pages you linked to are only the subset of fixes needed for the compilers/developer tools, not the whole OS.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes solaris 10 is sun os 5.10 http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/solaris/versions/

Comment: Thnx for the reply.. the latest version for 5.10 it shows was released on Jan 2005 !

No other major release after that . Also, which latest fix pack etc I shld get for my system ?

Comment: There have been updates on that of course. I think the last was 10/09

Comment: The ocf.berkeley.edu page is not being kept up to date - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29#Version_history is more current.

Answer (score 1):

This is question is a little bit old, but it showed up on the front page today so I'll update and add some missing info.

At current (2012-08) the most recent release of Solaris 10 from Oracle is Solaris 10 8/11. Solaris 10 downloads are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html).

You should be running the most recent release, plus any patches available (unless otherwise instructed by Oracle support). To find patches available run:

```
smpatch analyze
```

To install them run:

```
smpatch update
```

There will be more patches available to you if you have a valid support contract.